# Replace anything between paragraph tags if it is a html tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove empty paragraphs from a string which is being pasted into a html textarea. I have this as a regular expression to do that.

```
var reg = /\<p( [a-zA-Z]*=((\"[^\"]*\")|(\'[^\']*\')))*\>\<\/p\>/g;
```

and it works okay. But, some of the data being pasted contains paragraphs that look like this.

```
<p><b></b></p>
```

So the regular expression does not work - as the paragraph, although it contains no actual text, does contain html tags.

Can anyone tell me please now to modify my regular expression so that it will not only replace paragraphs with no content with an empty string, but will also replace paragraphs where the only content is html tags.

At the moment text like this.

```
<p style="margin:0px;"></p>
<p>Fred</p>
<p style="margin-left:10px;"></p>
<p><b></b></p>
<p>Jim</p>
```

is being modified so it then becomes

```
<p>Fred></p>
<p><b></b></p>
<p>Jim</p>
```

I need it to become

```
<p>Fred</p>
<p>Jim</p>
```

Comment: give some sample and expected output

Comment: Whoever down votes a question just after it being posted, should clarify the reason

Comment: Obligatory link: [**Don't parse HTML with a regex**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!! Use an HTML parser.

Comment: If nesting is one level as you mentioned in question, we can do it. But, it is impossible to do for recursive nesting which is general HTML syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<p[^>]*>(?:\s*<(\w+)>\s*<\/\1>\s*|\s*)<\/p>
```

and replace by empty

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sSXWM8/1/)

```js
const regex = /<p[^>]*>(?:\s*<(\w+)>\s*<\/\1>\s*|\s*)<\/p>/g;
const str = `<p style="margin:0px;"></p>
<p>Fred</p>
<p style="margin-left:10px;"></p>
<p><b></b></p>
<p>Jim</p>`;
const subst = ``;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I know you are not supposed to, but, to me, it is rude not to say 'thank you'. So, 'thank you' for your help.